# change appdomain of a nuget project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am running ASP.NET MVC web application, with a nuget project merged inside of it. So basically I have got two projects inside of one. The nuget project is being initialized when ASP.NET MVC starts up.

ASP.NET MVC runs in `DefaultDomain` appdomain, while nuget project runs in something like that - `/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-(...)`, so I assume that it runs as a root. Now, I don't want it to be run as a root, anything but a root would be good. How can I change it?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean "runs as a root"? (Note that there is no "root" user in Windows if you refer to Unix "root" user)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yeah sorry, my bad. Root is my username on windows, so I assume that it runs as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change AppDomain where each individual sites are running. The name is set by ASP.Net runtime (there is one default AppDomain and one AppDomain per site).

Depending on your actual problem - either create new app domain or be happy with default ASP.Net setup.

Note that: projects don't "run in an app domain", in most cases resulting exe/dll is *loaded* into an AppDomain... There is no direct correlation between projects and AppDomains.